# How do I retrieve a set number of characters that precede and follow a key word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 to query data.

One of the columns is a freeform text box and I need data from the column but I don't want the whole paragraph back. I want to look for a keyword like 'obsolete' and retrieve the 20 characters that precede it and the 20 characters that follow it.

If I applied the solution to the following paragraph where I was looking for the word obsolete and the 20 char before and after it:

> In 1992, Tim Berners-Lee circulated a document titled “HTML Tags,” which outlined just 20 tags, many of which are now obsolete or have taken other forms. The first surviving tag to be defined in the document, after the crucial anchor tag, is the paragraph tag. It wasn’t until 1993 that a discussion emerged on the proposed image tag.

It would return: "ny of which are now obsolete or have taken other"

NOTE: I am an end user, not admin, so please refrain from advising me that we shouldn't allow a free form text box if that's an issue.

Comment: String functions would help, no doubt: CHARINDEX & SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the result using this query :

```
DECLARE @Paragraph nvarchar(max) = 'In 1992, Tim Berners-Lee circulated a document titled “HTML Tags,” which outlined just 20 tags, many of which are now obsolete or have taken other forms. The first surviving tag to be defined in the document, after the crucial anchor tag, is the paragraph tag. It wasn’t until 1993 that a discussion emerged on the proposed image tag.'
DECLARE @Keyword nvarchar(50) = 'obsolete'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Paragraph, CHARINDEX(@Keyword, @Paragraph) - 20, LEN(@Keyword) + 40)
```

Comment: This one works! For some reason the answer provided by @SQLChao worked using the example I provided but when I translated it over to my query it pulled the 20 char before 'maximum' (the word I actually want) and ALL of the text that followed rather than just the 20 characters that followed. Than you!

Comment: Pleased to hear that your problem is sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @Paragraph VARCHAR(MAX) = 'In 1992, Tim Berners-Lee circulated a document titled “HTML Tags,” which outlined just 20 tags, many of which are now obsolete or have taken other forms. The first surviving tag to be defined in the document, after the crucial anchor tag, is the paragraph tag. It wasn’t until 1993 that a discussion emerged on the proposed image tag.'
DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(20) = 'obsolete'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Paragraph, PATINDEX('%' + @SomeString + '%', @Paragraph) - 20, LEN(@SomeString) + 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out how to grab an IP address from a string of text. Here's how I did it:

```
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' '),
        CHARINDEX('ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ')), 24) = 'ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS :'
        THEN
            replace(replace(replace(replace(
                RIGHT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' '),
                CHARINDEX('ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ')), 40),15)
                    ,' ',''),'S',''),'E',''),'Y','')
    WHEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' '),
        CHARINDEX('ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ')), 23) = 'ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS:'
        THEN
            replace(replace(replace(replace(
                RIGHT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' '),
                CHARINDEX('ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CS.Comment, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ')), 39),15)
                    ,' ',''),'S',''),'E',''),'Y','')
    ELSE NULL
    END [IP]
```

I figured out that the one consistent thing in each text box was 'originating ip address' but that showed up as either 'ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS:' or 'ORIGINATING IP ADDRESS :' and I could anchor my code to those 2 strings. Also each IP address was followed by one of two words and some combination of spaces so if an IP address had fewer than 15 characters some combination of ' ',S,E, or Y would creep into my results. The natural solution there was to just replace those characters with nothing so it very neatly trimmed the garbage off of the end of each IP address.

I've learned a lot over the last year.  :-)